Multi-information DQN
Hypothetically how would one pass two sets of information to a DQN on the same map.
Imagine you want to pass information for DQN that is conducted search and rescue in a space and needs to both know the places already covered and the current location of other agents.
In the coverage question there are three types of spaces:

searched (and traversable)
space not search yet (and traversable)
impassable space

For the map of current agents in the spaces there are two types of nodes:

Agent present
No agents present

An agent can only go to a space there is traversable where there are no agents.
Would it be better to pass multiple effective arrays into the DQN or one map that contains both set of information. Or is there another solution?
I have been doing a lot of reading for the DQN inputs. I am uncertain of how to proceed. I have tried simple implementation of both methods explained above.
